# C++ Trying to Find An Alternative Way to Implement Forward Declaration

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, c++03, incomplete-type

I asked this question 2 days ago, but I had to fix some lines. So here my question again:

I have multiple classes and have written them in an order. First class has an enum, but I want to move it to the class that is below all other classes. This is where problem begins. Since the last class will have that enum, members that use enum in first class gives error.

Here is the initial code:

file.hpp:

```
class A
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        eOk = 0x00;
        eError = 0x01;
    }myEnum_et;

    typedef myEnum_et(*callbackType)(B*);
    callbackType myCallback;

public:
    void foo1(callbackType callbackParam)
    {
        myCallback = callbackParam;
    }

    myEnum_et foo2()
    {
        return myCallback;
    }
};

class B
{
public:

    A::myEnum_et foo3(A *a)
    {
        if(a->foo2() != A::eOk) return A::eError;
        else return A::eOk;
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    B *b;

    void foo4(B *new_b)
    {
        b = new_b;
    }    
};
```

What I want to do is:

```
class C;
class B;

typedef C::myEnum_et(*callbackType)(B*);

class A
{
public:
    callbackType myCallback;

public:
    void foo1(callbackType callbackParam)
    {
        myCallback = callbackParam;
    }

    C::myEnum_et foo2()
    {
        return myCallback;
    }
};

class B
{
public:

    C::myEnum_et foo3(A *a)
    {
        if(a->foo2() != C::eOk) return C::eError;
        else return C::eOk;
    }
};

class C
{
public:
    typedef enum
    {
        eOk = 0x00;
        eError = 0x01;
    }myEnum_et;

    B *b;

    void foo4(B *new_b)
    {
        b = new_b;
    }    
};
```

As seen above, I just want to move myEnum_et from class A to class C and move function pointer to out of class A's scope. As you know, declaring class C at the top of code is not enough for those that will use myEnum_et. I guess the reason is that compiler needs full definition of class C. Here is the error :

> #71 Incomplete type is not allowed.

I am aware that code's readability is ugly. I just wanted show that all classes' definition depend on each other and want to use forward declaration(or other solutions) at this class order. Classes' methods may not make any sense, my purpose is just to implement forward declaration somehow. By the way, I use C++03 so I am kinda limited.

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72743954/edit) your original question rather than opening a new one

Comment: fwiw, you need not consider member function definitions, because they should be placed in a source file.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Yes, I know, but my problem is handling forward declaration. These methods are in test phase. I just want to know if it is possible

Comment: @AlanBirtles I thought opening new one will appear on homepage. The question I asked 2 days ago didn't appear on homepage so that there was only 16 views.

Comment: sorry, maybe you didnt understand. When you place the definitions in the header then you might get errors that you wont get without them. Also they distract a little from the actual issue and are not necessary to show the problem with forward declarations

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Okay I will try moving them to .cpp file.

Comment: If you edit the question it will reappear in the active questions just the same as a new question. You have to be aware that stack overflow is a huge site with new questions coming in all the time so it's not unlikely that your question won't appear on the home page. Reposting a question isn't a way to game the system

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number What about the function pointer I wrote at the top of it ? I just wrote return type of function pointer as myEnum_et and it gives same error. I didn't write any methods here, just enum. Does it have something to do with defining methods in .cpp file ?

Comment: no not this part. But for example `if(a->foo2() != C::eOk) return C::eError;` needs `A` to be a complete type, but to declare (not define!) `C::myEnum_et foo3(A *a)` a forward declaration of `A` is sufficient

Comment: `C` only needs a forward declaration of `B` so it can come first, then the rest is no issue: https://godbolt.org/z/vqqe679r4